# How to recover deleted files with original filenames on FAT32 usb?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have tried several products to recover the data.

I have all of the original files thanks to photorec and foremost however, the images are useless without the correct filenames.

I have all of the correct filenames as well thanks to testdisk but the files are incomplete and corrupt when recovered using its undelete option.

How do I get both the correct, full data and the original filenames?

**Things I have tried:**

I was going to cross reference the testdisk names with the photorec files based on filesize but the sizes are inconsistent.

I looked into more advanced options of testdisk but can't seem to find anything that would cause truncated files. I might still be wrong in this aspect.

Photorec and Foremost don't seem to have filename recovery and only seem to have filenaming based on offset and size schemes, so they alone can't do the job.

I have tried to recover the filenames from the exif/metadata but the dates and filenames are all the same as the recovered files creation times and names which didn't really lead anywhere.

**Clarification:**

Only the files recovered from testdisk are corrupt, they seem to all be about 80% of the filesizes that I recovered successfully with photorec. The problem is, the photos that are correct don't have the right filenames which are needed for the study they are involved with.

**Final Progress:**

Sorry guys, after probably investing too much time trying to recover the files, I discovered that the girl I was doing this for took it to her IT department and he defrag'd the drive for some reason, rendering nearly all of the files useless and overwritten. Oh well, I managed to recover 6 of 60 files. Not terrible but still means a lot of work needs to be redone. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried Recuva?

Comment: There aren't very many free tools that attempt to use the filesystem itself for recovery, which is why your files come out without names or nested in their original directory tree. you can try Recuva, or if you want to pay for it, Easus recovery, but remember, these tools can only work if the damage to your disk does not intersect with critical sections of the filesystem's metadata. If the File Allocation Table or partition metadata are sufficiently damaged, it will be impossible to perform the recovery you want.

Comment: Fortunately, the disk is still healthy. I am simply trying to undo a delete that someone did on a folder. Nothing new has been written to the drive and I actually have all of the data, I just need to figure out the names that correspond to which file.

Comment: Sounds like data recovery won't be possible if the detected files that can be recovered is corrupt

Comment: Also, Sometimes disk utilities (like ddrescue and spinrite or even good old chkdsk) can get you a clean image off a damaged disk, so they are a low risk option, but be sure to never run spinrite or chkdsk on a disk that is not mechanically healthy (check the SMART stats first). image the drive with ddrescue before attempting that kind of repair.

Comment: This is a USB flash drive SpinRite won't be very helpful in a case like this

Comment: yep, you are correct. I'm speaking catagorically about differant types of recovery software, their particular uses, and when to use them. Perhaps I'm being overzealous, but it is important to know what tool is used in what circumstances.

Comment: Why are the file names so important? The content of the images and the metadata will tell you most of what you need to know. If you can get access to a Windows system, Convar's free [PC Inspector](http://www.pcinspector.de/default.htm?language=1) is excellent, and should recover the filename, apart from the first character, which on FAT is set to 0xFF when a file is deleted to indicate a free directory entry.

Comment: @AFH, is there an easy way to recover names from metadata in linux? (I can use Windows if I must)

Comment: They are not stored there, but if they came from a camera then they are usually numbered sequentially, so you can infer the name by arranging in date order. Tips: set write protect if it's available, before you do any investigations; also, use `dd` to create a file image of the drive, so you have something to go back to if recovery attempts make matters worse. Note that PC Inspector never writes to the corrupt disc, but recovers what data it can to a host directory.

Comment: I can't seem to find any way to relate the filenames to the files that are complete. Is there a way to make testdisk to get the whole files?

Answer (score 1):

Use audit.txt of Foremost to regain original filenames:

```
File.read("audit.txt").scan(/-{4,}\n(File: .*?\n.*?)(?=-{4,})/m).flatten.map{|z| 
   f1=z.scan(/File: (.*?)\n/).flatten[0];
   f2=z.scan(/[0-9]+:\t(.*?) \t/m).flatten;
   extension=File.extname(f1);

   [
    f1,
    f2.find{|q| File.extname(q)==extension}
   ]
}.each{|k,v| 
  extension=File.extname(k);
  dirname=extension.sub(".","")
  File.rename("#{dirname}/#{v}","#{dirname}/#{k}")
}
```

Run this Ruby program in the directory of "audit.txt".

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's the limitations of using Freeware recovery applications. Why not try EaseUS, Stellar Phoenix or some other recovery suites that may have relatively higher chances of full recovery with their actual file names?

I don't have idea about which exactly works but have heard that paid recovery applications are more reliable and efficient.